# Synonym for "financial power"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a synonym for "financial power"?

> With his newfound _____, he ....

The idea being people who have ___ can throw their weight around, gain better representation, etc..

The word doesn't have to itself mean specifically "relating to money" if it can idiomatically be used to refer to economic power.

"Capital" seems like it would fit, but this has too specific a meaning. The word I am looking for more so describes a business or individual who, after investing some capital (be it originally time or money), makes massive return on their investment, and suddenly has great ____.

Comment: *Wealth*! Or maybe *social capital*?

Comment: Yeah, "Wealth!"

Comment: _Money_. (Money is power.)

Comment: Solvency, which would be particularly apt if he or she came into money rather suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

An often used word for financial power is *means*.

> 2 Money; financial resources

> ‘he came from a family of very modest means’

> 2.1 Wealth.

> ‘exclusive hotels that are priced so that only people of means can stay’

> ‘You have had the means under your control for quite some time now.’

> 2.2 Resources; capability.

> ‘every country in the world has the means to make ethanol’

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/means

The other expression often used is *wherewithal*, defined as:

> The money or other means needed for a particular purpose.

> ‘they lacked the wherewithal to pay’

> ‘They don't have the money or the wherewithal to want to slam him on environment.’

> ‘All have the wherewithal to pay a premium for the quality of home life York offers.’

> ‘A gusher of cash flow is giving businesses the wherewithal to increase their capital outlays.’

> ‘Since he lacks the financing to build, he lacks the wherewithal to complete his side of the contract.’

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wherewithal

Comment: _Wherewithall_ seems _right on the money_ to me. :)

Comment: @Zoidmania i would like to spell it that way too. But   the dictionaries use only one l.

Comment: It's an old habit I'm trying to dig myself out of, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Wealth & Influence or a confluence of the two in an order that suits your needs. Usually the standard parts of speech in relating countries. eg: China's expansive influence has been bought by its Wealth and deep pockets.

Answer (score 0):

> makes massive return on their investment, and suddenly has great ____.

Because of this part of the post, the phrase **windfall profits** came to mind, though I don't know if you're looking for emphasis on the *sudden* nature of the financial power, rather than the money itself:

> A piece of unexpected good fortune, typically one that involves receiving a large amount of money. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/windfall))